# Vim...what argument represents the matching word in a search?

Tags: vim

What exactly is the syntax for say `:s:you:your` except to just append the r to you rather than replace it fully?

I tried `:s:you:\1r` but no luck there. I swear I had seen syntax like this for similar commands, but apparently was wrong.

Comment: Close. It's `\0` you would have used but Christian's answer is even shorter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for '&' in the replace part.

so `:s/you/&r/`
will do what you want.

Comment: +1, you can drop the trailing `/` to make it even shorter